# Spring Boot - boolean in JSON GET request turns null in database

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot

The hasMarketingEmailConsent on the following JSON GET request turns null in mysql database.

{
{
"userName" : "canyonlee",
"email" : "hellohappy@gmail.com",
"hasMarketingEmailConsent" : true
}
}

Code below is when this boolean variable is declared:

```
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String userName;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime joinedTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Column @JsonProperty("hasMarketingEmailsConsent")
    private boolean hasMarketingEmailsConsent;

.....
}
```

Controller looks like this

```
@PostMapping("/new")
public void addNewMember(@RequestBody Member member){
    memberService.addNewMember(member);
}
```

The mysql database looks like this

```
id | email                |user_name  |joined_time                 |has_marketing_emails_consent
13 | hellohappy@gmail.com | canyonlee | 2020-10-24 21:01:25.205670 | 0x00
```

as you can see everything else gets inserted to database normally except the boolean. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the type of `has_marketing_emails_consent` is database ?

Comment: ran the following query --> [SHOW FIELDS FROM tablename]

result -> [has_marketing_emails_consent | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |]

type showing as bit(1) - not sure if this is intended for booleans. the tables in my sql were created by hibernate.thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think i figured out why - "0x00" in mysql is just 8 zeros which is 0 - i believe that's how they store boolean false. I tried sending over a true then it became "0x01". I wasn't familiar with 0x00 being the short form of 8 zeros.

Comment: 0x used for the number in octal